# How to tell if AWS Elastic Network Interface (ENI) has a public IP address using Python boto?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, amazon-vpc

I am auditing security groups and right now my task is to find ENIs with no public IP addresses with inbound security group rules that reference public IP addresses.

I have code that iterates over ENIs and looks at the Security Groups attached to each one and I'm hoping to recycle that.  Here's that code:

```
used_sgs = {}
enis = ec2_conn.get_all_network_interfaces()
for eni in enis:
    eni_sgs = eni.groups
    for sg in eni_sgs:
        sgn = sg.name
        if sgn not in used_sgs:
           used_sgs[sgn] = 0
        used_sgs[sgn]+=1
```

Is there an attribute I can sniff to see if an ENI has a public IP?  Or do I have to take some other route (iterate over instances, or grab the ENI attachment, or something else)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
eni.publicIp
```

Not all enis have publicIp associated with them. So check if publicIp attribute exists and then get that value

```
for eni in enis:
  if hasattr(eni, 'publicIp') and eni.publicIp:
    print eni.id, eni.publicIp
```

Comment: Great, thanks!  Interestingly enough, neither the boto docs NOR eni.__dict__ exposed a 'publicIp' attribute I could sniff.  Or did I miss something?

Comment: As I mentioned, not all ENIs has publicIp associated with them. If you dump the dict of ENI that has a publicIp, you will see that attribute.



>>> 'publicIp' in enis[0].__dict__
True
>>> 'publicIp' in enis[1].__dict__
False